userns-remap vs non root image user
Im currently playing around with docker and now start thinking about security. As I understand it there are (at least) two ways to secure docker containers. Either each container has to run with a non root user or I can use the userns-remap feature.
I'm now wondering, is it secure when I run all my containers with root useres if I enable namespace remapping?
I could remap everything to a user called exec and as long as this user is not part of the docker group, even when a container is compromised and the attacker can somehow break out of it, the system would still be pretty secure right? The attacker then has no root access and can't start/stop any containers (not even with docker.sock) as it's not in the docker group.
Am I right in my assumptions or do you have any other thoughts on this I might have missed?


I could remap everything to a user called exec

That's not how the remap works. The remap creates a uid/gid namespace range for containers to be isolated within. If that mapping goes from 100000-165535, uid 0 in the container would appear as uid 100000 on the host, and similarly uid 1000 would appear as 101000. Typically the user namespace is configured to map to high uid/gid values that do not overlap with any host users for security. This also means that host volumes will have permission issues, so you'll want to avoid them, and limit yourself to named volumes managed by docker.
Running containers as a non-root user is a good best practice. However, you'll find some popular images will default to root and may not work if configured to run as a non-root user. It's also common for every image to pick an arbitrary and different non-root uid, making it difficult to specify a single host user for all containers.
There's also a third option, running the container engine rootless. This is implemented with a lot of different technologies that may cause compatibility issues, and it leverages userns (since as a user you cannot run things as root on the host without escalating privileges, but you can access the /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid mappings). Running rootless is significantly more secure since no containers are running as the host root user ever, and a vulnerability of the container engine will only give you access to the user on the host and not root on the host.

Thanks for the explanation! So you would prefer rootless mode most of the time? I could get around the permission problem by setting the startId in /etc/subuid and subgid to the same id as my new user, couldn't I? So root inside the container would map to the new user on the host

rootless provides the most security at the cost of usability. Many people want the usability of running the engine as root, and often even want host mounts to map to host users. If you setup userns with an overlapping uid/gid range with the host, you lose much of the advantage of having a userns. A container escape has access to a user on the host, potentially with valuable data, and possibly with access to commands like sudo.
